# Generalization of the result of $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{-x^2} \sin \left(x^2\right)}{x^2} d x$.

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals, gaussian-integral

When I came across the integral $$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{-x^2} \sin \left(x^2\right)}{x^2} d x,$$
I didn’t know how to deal with it. After struggling, I thought of Feynman’s trick and Euler formula and tried by letting
$$I(a)=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{-x^2} \sin \left(a x^2\right)}{x^2} d x$$
with $I(0)=0.$
Differentiating $I(a)$ w.r.t. $a$ yields
$$
I^{\prime}(a)=\int_0^{\infty} e^{-x^2} \cos \left(a x^2\right) d x
$$
Inevitably, I used the Euler formula $e^{i x}=\cos x+i \sin x$ to group the functions in terms of exponential function.
$$
\begin{aligned}
I^{\prime}(a) & =\int_0^{\infty} e^{-x^2} \cos \left(a x^2\right) d x \\
& =\operatorname{Re} \int_0^{\infty} e^{-x^2} e^{i a x^2} d x \\
& =\operatorname{Re} \int_0^{\infty} e^{-(1-i a) x^2} d x
\end{aligned}
$$
which is a [Gaussian integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral): $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-a(x+b)^2} d x=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}$ for any $Re(a)>0$.
$$
\begin{aligned}
I’(a) &=\operatorname{Re}\left(\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2 \sqrt{1-i a}}\right)\\ I(a)&=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} \operatorname{Re}\left[\frac{(1-i a)^{\frac{1}{2}}}{-\frac{1}{2} i}\right]\\ \therefore \int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{-x^2} \sin \left(x^2\right)}{x^2} d x&= \sqrt{\pi}\operatorname{Re}\left[i \sqrt{\sqrt{2} e^{-\frac{\pi i}{4}}}\right]\\&   = \sqrt{\sqrt{2} \pi} \operatorname{Re}\left[i\left(\cos \frac{\pi}{8}-i \sin \frac{\pi}{8}\right)\right]\\&= \sqrt{\sqrt{2} \pi} \sin \frac{\pi}{8}
\end{aligned}
$$
As a bonus, $$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{-x^2} \sin \left(x^2\right)}{x^2} d x = \sqrt{\sqrt{2} \pi} \cos \frac{\pi}{8} $$

---

**My Question**
:Can we generalise the method to the integral$$
I_n=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{-x^n} \sin \left(x^n\right)}{x^n} d x?
$$

---

Fortunately, the answer is positive and decent as:
$$
\int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{-x^n} \sin \left(x^n\right)}{x^n} d x= \frac{2^{\frac{n-1}{2 n}}}{n-1} \Gamma\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) \sin \left(\frac{\pi(n-1)}{4 n}\right)
$$
where $n$ is any real number greater than $1$.

Proof:
Replacing the number 2 in the original integral by $n$ gives
$$
I_n^{\prime}(a)=\operatorname{Re} \int_0^{\infty} e^{-(1-i a) x^n} d x
$$
Letting $(1-i a) x^n \mapsto x$ transforms the derivative into

$$
\begin{aligned}
I_n ^{\prime}(a) & =\operatorname{Re}\left[\frac{1}{n(1-i a)^{\frac{1}{n}}} \int_0^{\infty} x^{\frac{1}{n}-1} e^{-x} d x\right] \\
& =\frac{1}{n} \operatorname{Re}\left[\frac{1}{(1-i a)^{\frac{1}{2}}}\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right] \\
& =\frac{1}{n} \Gamma\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) \operatorname{Re}\left[\frac{1}{(1-i a)^{\frac{1}{n}}}\right]
\end{aligned}
$$
Integrating back yields

$$
\begin{aligned}
I_n(1)-I_n(0) & =\frac{1}{n} \Gamma\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) \operatorname{Re} \int_0^1(1-i a)^{-\frac{1}{n}} d a \\
I(1)& =\frac{1}{n} \Gamma\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) \operatorname{Re}\left[\frac{(1-i a)^{-\frac{1}{n}+1}}{-i\left(\frac{1}{n}+1\right)}\right]_0^1 \\
& =\frac{1}{n-1} \Gamma\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) \operatorname{Re}\left(i(1-i)^{\frac{n-1}{n}}\right)
\end{aligned}
$$
Now we can conclude that

$$
\begin{aligned}
I& =\frac{1}{n-1} \Gamma\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) \operatorname{Re}\left[i\left(\sqrt{2} e^{-\frac{\pi}{4}}\right)^{\frac{n-1}{n}}\right] \\
& =\frac{1}{n-1} \Gamma\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) \operatorname{Re}\left[i 2^{\frac{n-1}{2 n}} e^{-\frac{\pi(n-1)}{4 n}}\right] \\
& =\frac{2^{\frac{n-1}{2 n}}}{n-1} \Gamma\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) \sin \left(\frac{\pi(n-1)}{4 n}\right)
\end{aligned}
$$

Any comments and alternative methods are highly appreciated.

Comment: It's sufficient to compute$$\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{s-1}e^{-ax}\sin(bx)\text{d}x
=\Im\left ( \int_{0}^{\infty} x^{s-1}e^{-(a-bi)x}\text{d}x \right ).$$

Answer (score 2):

By use of special function Gamma function...

$\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-x^n}\sin(x^n)}{x^n}dx &=\Im\left(\int_0^{\infty}x^{-n}e^{-(1-i)x^n}dx\right)\\
&=\Im\left(\frac{(1-i)^{\frac{n-1}{n}}}{n}\int_0^{\color{red}\infty}\large u^{\frac{1-2n}{n}}e^{-u}du\right)\hspace{1cm}\small\text{(By substituting $u=(1-i)x^n$) }\\
&=\Im\left(\frac{(1-i)^{\frac{n-1}{n}}}{n}\Gamma\left(\frac{1-n}{n}\right)\right)\hspace{1cm}\small\text{(Since $s-1=\frac{1-2n}{n}\implies s=\frac{1-n}{n}$) }\\
&=\frac{\Gamma{(\frac1n)}}{1-n}\Im\left(\left(\sqrt2\Large e^{-\frac{\pi i}{4}}\right)^{\frac{n-1}{n}}\right)\hspace{1cm}\small\text{ $\left(\Gamma\left(\frac{1-n}{n}\right)=\frac{n}{1-n}\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)$} \\
&=\frac{\Gamma{(\frac1n)}}{1-n}\large2^{\frac{n-1}{2n}}\Im\left(\Large e^{-\frac{\pi(n-1) i}{4n}}\right)\\
&=\frac{\Gamma{(\frac1n)}}{n-1}\large2^{\frac{n-1}{2n}}\sin\left(\frac{\pi(n-1)}{4n}\right)
\end{align}$